# Prevent the system from attempting to boot from a ZFS drive

Tags: hard-drive, mbr, freebsd, zfs, freenas

Lets say you can't access the bios to change the boot order of a drive, How would you go about booting from a particular drive.

Is it possible to make every other drive 'unbootable' and thus making the remaining drive the only way for the computer to boot? Or is this scenario impossible to solve?

**Edit** - More about the situation

So I've had this laptop for awhile where the screen and the HDMI port of the laptop was not working. I wanted to put it to use and make it into a NAS so I flashed a copy of freenas to a USB drive using my desktop machine(using a vm) and plugged it into my laptop(no internal hard drive) and got it to work. Then i added a external hard drive to the laptop and am using it happily :)

But i wanted to check if I take the external drive out of the enclosure and add it inside my laptop, if that would work. But sadly it didn't and I'm sure it's because the laptop is trying to boot from the internal hard drive.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: Did you tried to swap SATA cables on motherboard to find that one drive you want to boot from?

Comment: Is the hard disk MBR or GPT partitioned? (Note that there is no such thing as a "ZFS drive", but a drive may hold a portion of, possibly a whole, a ZFS pool.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If i'm correct its GPT since freenas moved away from using MBR

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the boot sector information from the drives that should be unbootable. Depending on previous OS installations on each disk it is either located in the master boot record (MBR) or on another partition (you have to either look it up or try it out by booting).

After that, if the first drive is selected by BIOS to boot and no boot info is found, the next drive will be tried in the order that has been set in the BIOS. If all other drives were marked as unbootable in the BIOS, you will get an error message and booting will not continue.

Normally, ZFS pool drives have no boot information themselves. A ZFS root pool (rpool) usually has boot information (although its mirrors may not have if configured wrong), but it depends on the system itself (Solaris, BSD, Linux etc.) where it is located.

Comment: Hi, can you give me any resources or more information about removing boot information from the rootpool. The system is BSD.

Comment: this is no guarantee.  some BIOS/firmwares will only "skip" removable drives, and if the first HDD found doesn't have a bootloader in MBR (or ESP, if UEFI) they will happily state that fact and ignore any additional HDDs.  from his description, i'd be surprised if this wasn't the case.  if he can't get into bios to change boot orders, he may be stuck using the HDD as external.